# Как сделать чтобы после запятой оставались только 2 цифры?

Tags: javascript, php

Вот выводится число 1.0099 , а как сделать чтобы выводилось 1.01 или хотя бы просто обрезалось до 1.00?

```html
function get_us_sk($summ, $user_id, $user_sk)
{
 if ($user_id && (0 < $summ) && ($user_sk == 0)) {
  $skidka = get_user_discount($user_id);

  if (0 < $skidka) {
   return ($summ / 100) * $skidka;
  }
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в php есть функция `round`
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php

для Js можно использовать `toFixed(<число знаков после запятой>)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

В вашем случае возвращаемое значение нужно записать так:

`return round( ($summ / 100) * $skidka, 2);`

Answer (score 2):

number_format — форматирует число с разделением групп ([ссылка](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php))

```
number_format(1.0099, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var num = 12.28646464;

console.log( num.toFixed(2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без округления к большему - меньшему:

```
var num = 12.28646464;

alert((parseInt(num*100))/100);
```